# BASH script for storing a Google geocode api lookup as a variable

Tags: bash, google-maps, curl, geolocation

I am trying to store a Google geocode lookup as a variable in BASH.

**Here's what I want to end up with**
(or something similar to it)

```
 _GEOINFO=$(curl "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="$_WHERE""
```

**Here's what almost works:**

```
_CITY="Grand rapids"
_STATE="Michigan"
_COUNTRY="United States of America"
_WHERE="\"$_CITY\",\"$_STATE\",\"$_COUNTRY\""
curl "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="$_WHERE""
```

**Here's what doesn't:**

```
curl "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$_WHERE"
```

**I've tried so many different variations on escaaping:**

```
\"$_WHERE\", \'\"$_WHERE\"\', \"${_WHERE}\",
```

**For most things I've tried, I get an error saying:**

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 10
```

Comment: By the way, if you do a search  like Toronto, Ontario, Canada it will work.  But for USA it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED IT!**

```
# store location information into variables 
_CITY="Grand rapids"
_STATE="Michigan"
_COUNTRY="United States of America"

# store all information as one string
_WHERE="$_CITY,$_STATE,$_COUNTRY"

# replace spaces with a +
_WHERE="${_WHERE// /+}"

# store the geo-location information into a variable
_GEOINFO=$(curl "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\"$_WHERE\""
```